# Replace XML path with a string in groovy file

Tags: java, groovy

I'm trying to replace a xml rootnode with a string, but it doesn't allow me.

I was trying to give it as 
`String str = "SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse";`

I should not repeat `SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse` in all these lines.

```
 def rootnode = new XmlParser().parseText(responseXml);
 status = rootnode.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.Status.text();
 errorCode = rootnode.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.Errorcode.text();
 errorInfo = rootnode.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.Errorinfo.text();
 referenceCode = rootnode.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.ReferenceCode.text();
 requestIp = rootnode.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return.RequestIP.text()
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that these "paths" are just a series of normal groovy property accesses, so you can store any intermediate point in the path as a variable and continue navigating from there:

```
deg rtn = rootnode.'SOAP-ENV:Body'.'ns1:creditCardResponse'.return
status = rtn.Status.text()
errorCode = rtn.Errorcode.text()
// etc.
```